# Netty Pipeline being executed out of order

Tags: java, proxy, netty

I am trying to figure out why my pipeline is being executed out of order.

I took the HexDumpProxy example and was trying to turn it into a http-proxy where I can look at all the traffic. For some reason the code is being executed backwards and I can't figure out why.

My server listens on 8443 and takes in the http content. I wanted to read the host header and create a frontend handler to route the data to the server, but my frontend handler executes first despite being last in the pipeline. I am unsure why it is running first I thought it would be execute in the following order.

1. LoggingHandler
2. HttpRequestDecoder
3. HttpObjectAggregator
4. HttpProxyListener
5. HttpReEncoder
6. HTTPProxyFrontEnd

The goal is to remove frontendhandler from the pipeline and have the HTTPProxy listener add it to the pipeline after reading the host header. but if I remove the frontend handler no data is transferred. Using breakpoints HTTPProxyFrontEnd is hit before HttpProxyListener. I am unsure why it is being executed so out of order.

Main

````
```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
try {
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
     .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
     .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
     .childHandler(new HttpProxyServerInitializer(REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT))
     .childOption(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false)
     .bind(LOCAL_PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
   } finally {
   bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
   workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
}
```
````

Pipeline

````
```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.*;
import io.netty.handler.logging.LogLevel;
import io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.util.SelfSignedCertificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;

public class HttpProxyServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer {

    private final String remoteHost;
    private final int remotePort;

    public HttpProxyServerInitializer(String remoteHost, int remotePort) {
        this.remoteHost = remoteHost;
        this.remotePort = remotePort;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
        ch.pipeline().addLast(
                new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO),
                new HttpRequestDecoder(),
                new HttpObjectAggregator(8192),
                new HttpProxyListener(),
                new HttpReEncoder(),
                new HTTPProxyFrontEnd(remoteHost, remotePort));
    }
}
```
````

Proxy Front end

````
```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.*;
import io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderResult;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.*;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.ServerCookieDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.ServerCookieEncoder;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;

import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import static io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
import static io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus.OK;
import static io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1;

public class HTTPProxyFrontEnd extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private final String remoteHost;
    private final int remotePort;
    private final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    private HttpRequest request;
    // As we use inboundChannel.eventLoop() when building the Bootstrap this does not need to be volatile as
    // the outboundChannel will use the same EventLoop (and therefore Thread) as the inboundChannel.
    private Channel outboundChannel;


    public HTTPProxyFrontEnd(String remoteHost, int remotePort) {
        this.remoteHost = remoteHost;
        this.remotePort = remotePort;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("HTTPFrontEnd");
        final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();
        // Start the connection attempt.
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
                .channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
                .handler(new HexDumpProxyBackendHandler(inboundChannel))
                .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
        ChannelFuture f = b.connect(remoteHost, remotePort);
        SocketAddress test = ctx.channel().remoteAddress();
        outboundChannel = f.channel();
        f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                if (future.isSuccess()) {
                    // connection complete start to read first data
                    inboundChannel.read();
                } else {
                    // Close the connection if the connection attempt has failed.
                    inboundChannel.close();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws InterruptedException {
        if (outboundChannel.isActive()) {
            outboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                    if (future.isSuccess()) {
                        // was able to flush out data, start to read the next chunk
                        ctx.channel().read();
                    } else {
                        future.channel().close();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private boolean writeResponse(HttpObject currentObj, ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        // Decide whether to close the connection or not.
        boolean keepAlive = HttpUtil.isKeepAlive(request);
        // Build the response object.
        FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(
                HTTP_1_1, currentObj.decoderResult().isSuccess()? OK : BAD_REQUEST,
                Unpooled.copiedBuffer(buf.toString(), CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

        response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

        if (keepAlive) {
            // Add 'Content-Length' header only for a keep-alive connection.
            response.headers().setInt(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());
            // Add keep alive header as per:
            // - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/draft-ietf-http-v11-spec-01.html#Connection
            response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION, HttpHeaderValues.KEEP_ALIVE);
        }

        // Encode the cookie.
        String cookieString = request.headers().get(HttpHeaderNames.COOKIE);
        if (cookieString != null) {
            Set<io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.Cookie> cookies = ServerCookieDecoder.STRICT.decode(cookieString);
            if (!cookies.isEmpty()) {
                // Reset the cookies if necessary.
                for (io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.Cookie cookie: cookies) {
                    response.headers().add(HttpHeaderNames.SET_COOKIE, io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.ServerCookieEncoder.STRICT.encode(cookie));
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Browser sent no cookie.  Add some.
            response.headers().add(HttpHeaderNames.SET_COOKIE, io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.ServerCookieEncoder.STRICT.encode("key1", "value1"));
            response.headers().add(HttpHeaderNames.SET_COOKIE, ServerCookieEncoder.STRICT.encode("key2", "value2"));
        }

        // Write the response.
        //ctx.writeAndFlush(response);

        return keepAlive;
    }

    private static void appendDecoderResult(StringBuilder buf, HttpObject o) {
        DecoderResult result = o.decoderResult();
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            return;
        }

        buf.append(".. WITH DECODER FAILURE: ");
        buf.append(result.cause());
        buf.append("\r\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        if (outboundChannel != null) {
            closeOnFlush(outboundChannel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        closeOnFlush(ctx.channel());
    }

    /**
     * Closes the specified channel after all queued write requests are flushed.
     */
    static void closeOnFlush(Channel ch) {
        if (ch.isActive()) {
            ch.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Hello, which/what kind of action is actually executed backwards? Which method is hit first? What is the class given by `.channel(ctx.channel().getClass())`?

Comment: Also why are you calling `read()` twice manually? (it is maybe a naive question). And writeResponse() is never called in the given code, aswell.

Comment: @bsaverino It does return HTTPProxyFrontEnd. Is that becuase it is calling Channel active in the frontend before the channel read in HttpProxyListener?


The code is a bit of a mess at the moment write response doesn't need to be used. I am calling read twice because I am snooping on the packet before reassembling it and passing it to the server.

Comment: Ok, I think it would be wise to share the HttpProxyListener code and the actual flow/sequence that poses an issue to you. I'm not sure of which action/request is leading to the reverse order (or not).